# How to prevent showing android permission window again once deny in android

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I need to implement a runtime permission in my application. But there is a problem When, I deny the permission alert window immediately showing again until allow the permission.

**My requesting permission code:**

```
 private void getPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS},
       GET_ACCOUNTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
  }
```

**Request handling code in onRequestPermissionsResult() method:**

```
   if (requestCode == GET_ACCOUNTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
      if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(QuranDataActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to prevent showing the alert window if deny the permission. How can i do that?

Comment: "How can i do that?" -- stop calling `requestPermissions()` right away after the user denies the permission. We cannot easily give you more focused assistance, as you have not provided a [mcve] demonstrating how you are requesting permissions.

Comment: @0xAliHn post code in question ,not in comments

Comment: @CommonsWare I have updated the post with code. Can you please suggest me now how can i do that?

Comment: The only time the permission dialog appears is because you are calling `requestPermissions()`. You will need to trace through your code to determine all the places and situations in which you are calling `requestPermissions()` and determine which of those is being called after the user denies the permission. For example, you could put breakpoints on all your `requestPermissions()` calls, then run your app in the debugger to see which is being called when.